# Disable ez-vcard PROPID

Tags: java, vcf-vcard

Is that possible to disable ez-vcard setting PROPID ?

I use ez-vcard to check some mandatories parameters for my application. I have an input file containing several vcards and I want to store each of them in my database. This is my Java code:

```
File vcf = ...;
List<VCard> vCards = Ezvcard.parse(vcf).all();
for (VCard vCard : vCards) {
    if (noMissingMandatoryValues(vCard)) {
        String vCardString = vCard.write();
        // record vCardString in database
    } else {
        // send an error message to the user
    }
}
```

With this code, if in my file I have:

> BEGIN:VCARD
>
> VERSION:4.0
>
> N:Doe;Jonathan;;Mr;
>
> FN:John Doe
>
> END:VCARD

Then this is the stored value in database:

> BEGIN:VCARD
>
> VERSION:4.0
>
> X-PRODID:ez-vcard 0.9.10
>
> N:Doe;Jonathan;;Mr;
>
> FN:John Doe
>
> END:VCARD

With the extra line `X-PRODID:ez-vcard 0.9.10` which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VCard vcard = ...
String vCardString = Ezvcard.write(vcard).prodId(false).go();
```